# BITS Credential Problem

Tags: c#, iis, file-upload, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I am facing the BITS Security problem.

I am creating the application where I am using t BITS to upload and download the file to the IIS server.

Now, my requirement is that I want to make my Virtual Directory password protected. I have done it through IIS>Directory Security. I disallow the anonymous access, but from the client side I'm not able to set the ID and password. My code is:

```
SharpBits.Base.BitsCredentials credz = new SharpBits.Base.BitsCredentials();

credz.UserName = "administrator@otssolutions.net";
credz.Password = "ad_10ots";
credz.AuthenticationScheme = SharpBits.Base.AuthenticationScheme.Digest;
credz.AuthenticationTarget = AuthenticationTarget.Server; 

BitsJob newJob = manager.CreateJob("vv", JobType.Upload);

newJob.AddFile("http://192.168.1.48/upload/abc.txt", @"C:\Temp\xyz.txt");
newJob.AddCredentials(credz);
newJob.Resume();
```

But it's not working...

I urgently need help with this.

Comment: gosh,  I hope that isnt the actual username/password!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the domain\user format?  E.g. `OTSSOLUTIONS\administrator` for the user name?  The domain name for your server may be different than your web domain name, so check your domain name by right clicking 'My Computer' and choosing 'Properties'.